# How to use popup within a tabitem to show that tab contents is loading in wpf mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using tabitem which contains a popup to show that data is loading from API .
The problem is the popup shows over the window, and it disappears whenever another tab is selected even though the data is still loading.

Is it possible for popup to be shown within the tab like other controls? and keep doing what it's doing whether the containing tab is selected or not?
what control do you suggest to use instead of popup if it's not the right one for this case?

Here is an example to explain:

**ViewModel:**

```
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        private bool showPopUp;
        public bool ShowPopUp
        {
            get { return showPopUp; }
            set
            {
                showPopUp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowPopUp));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        MainWindowViewModel model = new MainWindowViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = model;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //loading data
            model.ShowPopUp = true;
            await Task.Delay(100000);
            model.ShowPopUp = false;
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<TabControl x:Name="tc">
            <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Tab1">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <Popup
                            Name="popUp1"
                            StaysOpen="True"
                            IsOpen="{Binding ShowPopUp, Mode=OneWay,
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            AllowDrop="True" Placement="Center" 
                            Height="90" Width="135">
                            <Grid Background="LightGray">
                                <TextBlock Text="Loading ..." Margin="32" FontSize="16" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                        <Button Height="30" Width="100" Content="Show popup" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem
                x:Name="tab2"
                Header="Tab2">
            </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I think there are logical issues in your code, I don't think there is a xaml part bug. you uses StaysOpen and IsOpen property in a good way. How about you do debug or write log when variable `model.ShowPopup` goes false?

Comment: The value changed to false only when the execution reaches statement: '''model.ShowPopUp = false;''', even when the popup is hidden as a result of selecting another tab.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice your comment. It's too late.. does `model.ShowPopUp` goes false when you click another tab?.. I mean when you select another tab, then the execution reaches following `model.ShowPopup=false` statement?

Comment: No, it doesn't.